# Accessing the Currently Selected Item in ComboBox of Manually Entered String

Tags: apache-flex

I just want to acquire the existing label from the currently selected item in a ComboBox.  I populated it with a DataProvider with a list of strings and it will not allow me to get the currently selected label, especially if I input a new one, not included in the DataProvider.  What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

If the DataProvider was specified in your project's ActionScript (inside an `<fx:Script>` inline tag or inside a a streamlined .as file) then you can easily access the selected label with the following example:

```
var selected:String = (String) data.getItemAt(myComboBox.selectedIndex);
```

If your DataProvider was specified in MXML, or in some other non-variable way, you can do this:

```
var items:ArrayCollection = (ArrayCollection) myComboBox.dataProvider;
var selected:String = (String) items.getItemAt(myComboBox.selectedIndex);
```

You may be asking the following questions, in which I'll answer now:

1. Why do I need to cast the result to a string?

   - Because DataProviders return Objects, and the .toString() method returns "[Object]".
2. Why isn't there some sort of `.text` property of `myComboBox` ?

   - The text someone enters is only used for searching, and can not be a value.

     - The combo box was not designed for this.
   - It is more efficient to return the index inside the DataProvider in which the value exists.